# Compiler warnings using AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, afnetworking

I am a newbie to AFNetworking and running a simple application to understand how AFNetworking is working. I am following [this tutorial on MobileTuts:](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/)

I am already included the AFNetworking library and also typed -fno-objc-arc into the Compile Sources for each AFNetworking file.

I included this portion into the implementation file:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=harry&country=us&entity=movie"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"JSON");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];
[operation start];
```

When I hit run, I have 14 semantic issues and the project failed.
For example one error is:

```
Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call.
```

Not sure how to solve this error. Need some guidance...

Comment: Please post the full error messages.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**:

Firstly `delete` `AFNetworking` `library` and clean project.

Now `download` [latest AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

`Add` again `AFNetworking` `library` and `build` the project.

Comment: I removed the  -fno-objc-arc  for all the files... But Now i have lexical or preprocessor issue... Included the coreservices and systemconfiguration frameworks and their headers files in pch file...

Comment: add -fno-objc-arc for all the files